# Why is magnetic field not accounted for in the theory of CRO

Tags: oscilloscope, electromagnetic

I’m reading the chapter on Oscilloscopes in Cooper’s *Electronic Instrumentation and Measurement Techniques*.

Nowhere in the theory of the working of CRO (like deflection sensitivity) does he take into account the effect of magnetic field that should definitely be present due to rapidly changing very high voltages (~1000 V) applied on the vertical plates (~10 MHz or more).

But I’m aware that the speed of electrons in CRO is huge (~1/10th the speed of light). So even small magnetic fields should affect the motion greatly. (Magnetic force has a cross product of velocity and field.)

So why is neglecting it reasonable?

Comment: I usually use the dictum of 'if it happens, it must be true'. Which means in this case, it doesn't appear to matter, so do something quantitative to see the relative sizes of force on the beam due to magnetic and electrostatic deflection. Hint, when you do have magnetic deflection (ever looked at the neck of an old style domestic TV CRT?), there are hundreds of turns carrying hundreds of mA. Compare that to the CRO with one 'turn' carrying - what? - estimate the charging current for the plates. Have you ever operated a CRT in an MRI machine with the field on? I have. What do you think happens?

Comment: I’m reading about them for the first time... Never used them before.

Comment: FYI: CRO = "cathode ray oscilloscope", a term I've not heard until today (I know them as analog or cathode ray tube oscilloscopes.)

Comment: @Atom Are you discussing the electrons in transit in the vacuum? Or electrons traveling in conductors, plates, etc., elsewhere? Either way, Neil's comments are helpful to consider. And probably the very best place to examine all of the details, related to what I think your question is more about, is an electron microscope's design and elements. In particular, the electron gun (wehnelt and emitter and emitter coatings), the electron column, and the electro-magnetic lens system. There are many papers on the topic.

Comment: The voltage swing across the plates is nowhere near 1000V (less than 100Vpp). The 1st accelerator  grid works on 1000V (up to 2000V in 20Meg CROs with the anode & 1st accelerator connected together), made up of -950V (or -1950V) on the cathode + 50V on the 1st accelerator and quiescent voltage of the plates. In a high speed CRO, which has a fine wire mesh in the tube to shield the electrons form the high anode voltage until they have been deflected, the deflection voltage is about 2.5V/cm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the speed of electrons in CRO is huge (~1/10th the speed of light). So
>   even small magnetic fields should affect the motion greatly.

Magnetic force is proportional to velocity, but the force required to produce the same deflection radius is proportional to velocity *squared*, so a faster beam will be deflected *less* than a slower beam.

> So why is neglecting it reasonable?

The force on the electron beam is perpendicular to the magnetic field, so to deflect the beam across the tube face the magnetic field has to be parallel to it. However when AC current is passed through a capacitor it generates a *circular* magnetic field between the plates. As the beam passes between the plates it is deflected first one way and then the other as it crosses magnetic fields going in either direction, so overall the deflections tend to cancel out.

[image]

In a typical Oscilloscope tube the capacitance between deflection plates is only 1~2pF, so the displacement current at normal operating frequencies is small. The magnetic field produced is equivalent to the field around a single wire passing the same current, so if the plates were eg. 10mm wide and had a capacitance 2pF, and 100V was applied at 1GHz causing a current of ~1A, then ~0.2 Gauss would be produced - less than half that of the Earth's magnetic field. And much of that would cancel out.

At extremely high frequencies the magnetic deflection could be large to have a noticeable effect, but then other effects of the high frequency also become apparent. At GHz frequencies the electrostatic deflection amplitude reduces because the electrostatic field changes as the electrons are passing between the plates. At even higher frequencies deflection varies depending on the phase when the beam exits the plates.

[image]

[image]

At frequencies high enough for the magnetic field to become noticeable the tube has probably already lost its ability to faithfully reproduce any waveform other than a sine wave, and the amplitude is highly frequency dependent even without considering magnetic effects.

Answer (score 1):

> So why is neglecting it reasonable?

For the earths field

\$ \vec{F}= q(\vec{E} + \vec{v}\times\vec{B})\$

A 1000V field compared to 25uT (earths field) crossed with 3e7m/s isn't negligible (750 from VxB when compared with 1000 from E). But the electron is being accelerated almost from rest so the E term is constant over the trajectory of the electron, whereas the VxB term increases as the velocity increases.

Most of the time, the magnetic field would not be aligned perpendicular to the magnetic field. Many CRT's (or CRO's) have [magnetic shielding](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mu_metal_CRT_shields.jpg), and CRT's are calibrated which can reduce the effects from local static magnetic fields.

If there is a small field, and the CRT is shielded, then I think the contribution from the magnetic field would be neglectable.

Anything stronger than the earths magnetic field and it *does affect the path of the electrons*

[image]
Source: https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/accelerate/resources/demonstrations/cathode-ray-tube

Comment: What about magnetic field due to rapidly changing input signal manifested as rapid voltage (and hence electric field) changes between the vertical deflection plates? Can it be avoided?

Comment: Back in the day grade 1 picture monitors (for broadcast) were actually calibrated for the earths field in their intended installation location! I know visitek had some issues with a set of screens shipped down under.